# spark history not start on ambari cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, ambari, apache-spark-2.0

we start the spark history as the following

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark2/sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

from the log

```
spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer-1-master01
```

we get

```
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED ServerConnector@14a54ef6{HTTP/1.1}
{0.0.0.0:18081}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

please advice what is solution in order to start the spark history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to kill the process (like a zombie History server) with the port already open, or change the port in Ambari to something else

A combination of `netstat -an`,  `ps -ef`, and `lsof` will help you find what process holds the port